# Can an iOS 10 application run on an iOS 9 device?

Tags: xcode, ios9, ios10

I'm really exited about using the new Xcode application, I wanted to know if it's possible to run an iOS 10 app on an iOS 9 device ?

Because I'm actually developing my app on Xcode 7 and I don't know if I must finish my app first to migrate it on Xcode 8 or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 8 will support older deployment targets than iOS 10 (just as Xcode 7 supports older deployment targets other iOS 9).  You just have to adjust your project settings as appropriate.

If you want to use iOS 10 features (i.e., elements of the SDK that are available from iOS 10 forward), you will need to use the [availability syntax in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID523) and ensure that you don't access those SDK elements on older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If your deployment target is iOS 9, you can run on an iOS 9 device. You can even write the app in Swift 3! I'm doing that with apps built in Xcode 8 right now.

But note that I can't submit those apps to the App Store until the Xcode 8 goes final. No beta can be involved in production of an app submitted to the App Store.